# Python Npyscreen Setting Colors To Widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, colors, themes, curses

So I'm trying to build a UI in npyscreen, however the documentation I'm reading is not very thorough:

http://npyscreen.googlecode.com/hg-history/6f7c0a23d255707deddc80501e81f97197c9628b/docs/UserDocumentation.html

Could somebody help me set the color of certain widgets? I can set the overall theme of the entire application like this:

```
npyscreen.setTheme(npyscreen.Themes.ColorfulTheme)
```

However I can only use default themes, and I can't control individual widgets. I also want to figure out how to put borders on widgets.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the colour of different widgets by passing in a color= argument to the constructor.  The name of the colour is a string taken from the theme you are using.